# UIActivityViewController leaking child view controllers in iOS 9

Tags: ios, memory-leaks, uikit, uiactivityviewcontroller

While profiling my app with Instruments I found that there is a leak related to the iOS share dialog. I did some digging and here are the results:

The `UIActivityViewController` seems to not free its child view controllers. Namely the `UIAlertController` and all its descendants (including 3 `UICollectionView`s with icons…) are still in memory after the alert controller was dismissed. And they get recreated every time the share dialog opens.

This bug is actually fixed in iOS 10, but is there maybe a work-around we could use to fix that problem in iOS 9?